# Wordpress custom mysql query without IN() sorting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I need a custom query to show posts in special taxonomy order. I use this query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id )
WHERE 1 =1
AND (
wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
IN ( 13, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 504 )
)
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'goods'
AND (
wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
)
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

but returned results are with automatically applied order, like this: IN ( 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 504 ).
How can i achieve results without any sorting?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

with

```
ORDER BY RAND()
```

or remove it completely

Answer (score 0):

Try this one ,this will order like ( 13, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 504 ) taxonomy order

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id )
WHERE 1 =1
AND (
wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
IN ( 13, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 504 )
)
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'goods'
AND (
wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
)
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY FIELD( 13, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 504 )
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

[**FIELD(str,str1,str2,str3,...)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field)